# Shell variable definition and substitution properly quoted in a one-liner?

Tags: bash, zsh

I want to replace a number of strings within a query with something like the following:

```
URL="sub.domain.tld" mysql -A --user=username --password="password" --host=hostname usernameuction -e "update core_config_data SET value = 'http://${URL}/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/unsecure/base_url'; update core_config_data SET value = 'https://${URL}/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/secure/base_url';"
```

This ALMOST works perfectly, except I have to add an export to it in order to make it work:

```
export URL="sub.domain.tld"; mysql -A --user=username --password="password" --host=hostname usernameuction -e "update core_config_data SET value = 'http://${URL}/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/unsecure/base_url'; update core_config_data SET value = 'https://${URL}/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/secure/base_url';"
```

How can I make this work WITHOUT the export whilst keeping the var on the same line as the command that is quoted in bash or zsh?

Comment: What is the trouble with using `export`?

Comment: I don't like additional exported vars floating around my shell so that I can also repeat var usage without stepping on something. Just good practice to keep it local to the command.

Comment: Your re-checked answer leaves the variable in the shell. Try `FOO=bar; echo $FOO` then `echo $FOO` which is thus not 'local to the command'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lose the `export`, but keep the semicolon between the variable definition and the `mysql` command:

```
URL="sub.domain.tld"; mysql -A --user=username --password="password" --host=hostname usernameuction -e "update core_config_data SET value = 'http://${URL}/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/unsecure/base_url'; update core_config_data SET value = 'https://${URL}/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/secure/base_url';"
```

Explanation: When you give a variable definition as a separate command, (e.g. `URL="sub.domain.tld"; mysql ...`), the variable is defined in the shell and applied when all subsequent commands (like `mysql ...`) are parsed, but is not exported to the environment of those commands. This is what you want.

When you export a variable, (e.g. `export URL="sub.domain.tld"; mysql ...`), the variable is defined in the shell and applied when subsequent commands are parsed, *and* is exported to the environment of those commands.

When you give a variable definition as a prefix to a command (e.g. `URL="sub.domain.tld" mysql ...`), it doesn't set the variable in the shell at all, instead it exports it to that one command's environment. This doesn't work for your situation at all, since the arguments to `mysql ... "... https://${URL}/ ..."` are expanded by the shell, not by `mysql`, you need the variable defined in the shell, not in `mysql`'s environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unset` to remove the exported name from your environment. As such:

```
export URL=sub.domain.tld; mysql ...; unset URL

$ export FOO=bar; echo $FOO; unset FOO
bar
$ echo $FOO
```

Also, you can execute the one liner in a sub-shell:

```
$ (export FOO=bar; echo $FOO)
bar
$ echo $FOO
```

What you are seeking is behavior that works like when a command is executed.  Like this:

```
/* foo.c */
main (void)
{ printf ("FOO: %s\n", getenv("FOO")); }

$ FOO=bar ./foo
FOO: bar
```

The environment for the call to `foo` is extended with FOO.  But, in your case, the environment is not extended, short of using `export`, when your mysql arguments are processed.  You could use a shell function:

```
$ foo () { echo "FOO: ${FOO}"; }
$ FOO=baz foo
FOO: baz
$ echo $FOO
```

Comment: Hrm, yes thanks, I already was familiar with these, but I'm asking this more out of curiosity and style.

Comment: Working unusually hard for your business... take me over 5k points!

Comment: Take me up a little too for my patronage! :P